# Приведение матрицы к Фробениусовой нормальной форме

Tags: матрицы, алгоритм

Как это запрограммировать наиболее эффективно?

Answer (score 3):

[Уэйн Эберли предлагает](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~eberly/Research/Papers/frobenius_report.pdf) рандомизированный субкубический алгоритм. Помимо математического обоснования, в статье приведен псевдокод. Сам не реализовывал.

Стандартные методы вроде как дают сложность O(n^3).